# List group shows entire list

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, grouping

I have a Enterprise SharePoint 2010 list view that is grouped by a choice column and shows the number of items in that group but when I expand any group it shows the entire list instead of just the grouping. Any suggestions or where to look to correct this would be very grateful.

Comment: There should be no issue on grouping. Can you try with other list? Please check that same problem repeats in other list also or not.

Comment: It is only happening to this one list.  I may just have to delete it and build a new one and copy the data back and see if it happens again.

Comment: Ok.. What is the result?

Comment: It shows the groups and when I expand the entire list is shown inside each group.

Comment: The column I am using to group by is a choice column.  If I try to apply a grouping to any of the other views for the list has the same effect. Some of the views I have are actually filtered columns.

Comment: I am not able to understand "If I try to apply a grouping to any of the other views for the list has the same effect. Some of the views I have are actually filtered columns". Can you attach screenshot?